# Uploading File to AEM DAM

Tags: adobe, sling, dam

I am working on a Project to upload files to AEM DAM through Java API. So was going through [this tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/uploading-files-aem1.html) to upload files in DAM.

But I am not able to get this code check as I am getting “Null Pointer Exception” @ ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);

Pasting the code as well which I am writing, just to let you know AEM is running on a different server and I am trying to connect to that server from my local, Idea is to deploy it as a Rest API in a different server from AEM.
Thanks in advance any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For AEM 6.1+ `resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null)` is restricted and will return null so this is expected behaviour.

Since you are using admin resource resolver, I can only assume that your want to do something that requires a broader access. This practice is not encouraged anymore and it is recommended to create a custom service user with relevant permissions.

Depending on the location of your code (servlet, JSP page, service etc.), you can get ResourceResolver from various methods as documented [here](http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/resourceresolver-from-resourceresolverfactory/).